# C# How to perform a live xslt transformation on an in memory object?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a function that takes 2 parameters : 1 = XML file, 2 = XSLT file, then performs a transformation and returns the resulting HTML.

Here is the function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Will apply an XSLT style to any XML file and return the rendered HTML.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlFileName">
/// The file name of the XML document.
/// </param>
/// <param name="xslFileName">
/// The file name of the XSL document.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The rendered HTML.
/// </returns>
public string TransformXml(string xmlFileName, string xslFileName)
{
    var xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFileName)
                  {
                      WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
                  };
    var xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.Load(xtr);

    var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(xslFileName);
    var stm = new MemoryStream();
    xslt.Transform(xd, null, stm);
    stm.Position = 1;
    var sr = new StreamReader(stm);
    xtr.Close();
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I want to change the function not to accept a file for the XML, but instead just an object. 
The object is exactly compatible with the xslt, if it was serialized to file. But I don't want to have to serialize it to a file first.

So to recap : keep the xslt coming from a file, but the xml input should an object I pass and would like to generate the xml from without any file system interaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can serialize the object to a string, load the string into a `XmlDocument`, and perform the transformation :

```
public string TransformXml(object data, string xslFileName)
{

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    string xmlString;
    using (StringWriter swr = new StringWriter())
    {
        xs.Serialize(swr, data);
        xmlString = swr.ToString();
    }

    var xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml(xmlString);

    var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(xslFileName);
    var stm = new MemoryStream();
    xslt.Transform(xd, null, stm);
    stm.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(stm);
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I just used this, but have to point out that I needed to change `Position` to `= 0`. Otherwise it worked as expected. =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that will turn an object into a XDocument (you can change it for XmlDocument if you aren't using XDocument yet).  Of course this will throw exceptions if the object is not serializeable.

```
public static XDocument ConvertToXml<T>(this T o)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer,o);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(builder.ToString());
    return XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

and here's the one for XmlDocument

```
public static XmlDocument ConvertToXml<T>(this T o)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer,o);
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(builder.ToString());
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: XslCompiledTransform needs a XmlDocument, not a XDocument... Otherwise, this is roughly the same as my idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you can use the XPathDocument to take a Stream, and since XPathDocument implements IXPathNavigable, it can be used for transformations:

```
 public string TransformXml(Stream xmlFile, string xslFileName) 
 { 
      var doc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);
      var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(); 
      xslt.Load(xslFileName); 
      var stm = new MemoryStream(); 
      xslt.Transform(doc, null, stm); 
      stm.Position = 1; 
      var sr = new StreamReader(stm); 
      return sr.ReadToEnd(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950764.aspx) which describes creating an `XPathNavigator` that can navigate the properties of an object graph, which is a pretty powerful combination of XPath and XSLT.